# Mask Money Jquery plug in

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mask

I am using below Jquery plug in. I am able to mask the values. On blur event i need to perform some validations like. Take two text box values and calulate them. There is no way we can un mask the value or conver into to float. 
http://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to provide ***much more detail and probably some code*** to receive a good answer, but here's how you could strip out only the decimal value of the masked input on `blur` (regular expressions are your friend):

```
function getFloat(text) {
    var regex = /\d+|\./g,
        matches,
        num = "";

    while(matches = regex.exec(text)) {
        num += matches[0];
    }
    return parseFloat(num) || 0;
}

$("#price1, #price2")
    .maskMoney({ showSymbol: true })
    .bind("blur", function() {
        var price1 = getFloat($("#price1").val());
        var price2 = getFloat($("#price2").val());

        $("#total").text((price1 + price2).toFixed(2));
    });
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/enJEe/

Again, providing some more detail about your problem will increase the odds of your question being answered quickly and correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Next time I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the new versions of the plugin, you can do this

```
$("#price1, #price2")
    .maskMoney({ showSymbol: true })
    .bind("blur", function() {
        var price1 = $("#price1").maskMoney('unmasked');
        var price2 = $("#price2").maskMoney('unmasked');

        $("#total").text((price1 + price2).toFixed(2));
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The most common method:

`$("#id").unmaskMoney();`

But this is also an option:

`$("#id").unmask();`